# Convert year to seconds in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

I'm stuck on an assignment which needs me to convert an input of years and print the result in seconds. The error message I get when I run the function is:

```
'*TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting*'
```

I can't really get my head around what's wrong...

```
def ageInSeconds():
    """
    Reads the age and converts to seconds.
    """
    ageYears = int(input("Tell me your age, please: "))
    seconds = ageYears * (365*24*60*60)
    print("\nBatman says you age in seconds is: " % seconds)
```

Comment: You don't have a `%` inside the string for `seconds` to replace...

Comment: you can get more precise value if you ask the birthday e.g., there is 13514 days between today and 1 Mar 1978 (birthday) therefore `13514*86400 + 18` SI seconds elapsed since then (at the same time of the day (taking into account possible difference in UTC offsets corresponding to the two dates)). `18` is the number of leap seconds since 1978-03-01.

Comment: related: [How to convert years to seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32658742/4279)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a `%d` inside the string.

```
print("\nBatman says you age in seconds is: %d" % seconds)
                                             ^
```

Else you can do

```
print("\nBatman says you age in seconds is:",seconds)  # Inbuilt feature of the print function
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Years = int(input("Tell me the year, please: "))

answer = Years * (365*24*60*60)

print("There are", answer, "seconds in a year/years")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page, especially the part about making sure your answer actually answers the question posed. Also, generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem. Finally, please see [How do I format my code blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).